# Why this find_all method (BeautifulSoup4) won't return all URLs properly?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble using BeautifulSoup4.

I'm trying to find every link on a certain html page (https://www.gov.br/pt-br/servicos/infrabr) under a specific div, this is my code:

```
for a in soup.find(class_='col-servico').find_all(href = True):
    print(a['href'])
```

This is the html block I'm interested on (its inside div class=col-servico):

```
<div class="servico_fieldset_outras_conteudo">
   <p style="text-align: justify; ">Agora, o Sistema Eletrônico do Serviço de Informação (e-SIC) está integrado 
ao&nbsp;<span><a href="http://fala.BR" class="linkified" target="_blank">Fala.BR</a></span>.
 Desenvolvida .</p>
   <p style="text-align: justify; ">Em conformidade com
 a&nbsp;
<span><a class="external-link" 
href="http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2011-2014/2011/lei/l12527.htm" target="_blank" title="" 
data-tippreview-enabled="false" data-tippreview-image="" data-tippreview-title="">
```

As you can see this block has two 'a' tags:

```
<span><a href="http://fala.BR" class="linkified" target="_blank">Fala.BR</a></span>

<span><a class="external-link" 
href="http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2011-2014/2011/lei/l12527.htm" target="_blank" title="" 
data-tippreview-enabled="false" data-tippreview-image="" data-tippreview-title="">
```

But my result is bringing only one:

```
http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2011-2014/2011/lei/l12527.htm
```

As you can see, it's only returning the 'planalto.gov.br' URL, and not the 'fala.BR' one. I can't see any difference between those two 'a' tags and I don't know why it isn't returning the first link. Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues I think. First, in the link you gave, there is no href for fala br in the given div. You can manually inspect:

```
import httpx

res = httpx.get("https://www.gov.br/pt-br/servicos/infrabr")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)

print(soup.find(class_="col-servico").prettify())
```

If we instead use the snippet you posted, we do get the fala BR href:

```
html = """
<div class="servico_fieldset_outras_conteudo">
   <p style="text-align: justify; ">Agora, o Sistema Eletrônico do Serviço de Informação (e-SIC) está integrado 
ao&nbsp;<span><a href="http://fala.BR" class="linkified" target="_blank">Fala.BR</a></span>.
 Desenvolvida .</p>
   <p style="text-align: justify; ">Em conformidade com
 a&nbsp;
<span><a class="external-link" 
href="http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2011-2014/2011/lei/l12527.htm" target="_blank" title="" 
data-tippreview-enabled="false" data-tippreview-image="" data-tippreview-title="">
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.find(class_="servico_fieldset_outras_conteudo").find_all(href=True):
    print(a["href"])

# Returns:
# http://fala.BR
# http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2011-2014/2011/lei/l12527.htm
```

Maybe just check to see if you're using the correct HTML in your processing

Comment: You are totally right. But I'm confused as hell. If I open the page on my browser I can see Fala.BR as an 'a' tag, but using your code I indeed get just the text 'Fala.BR':

<p style="text-align: justify; ">Agora, o Sistema Eletrônico do Serviço de Informação (e-SIC) está integrado ao<span>Fala.BR</span>

Comment: It seems some javascript is processing the link afterwards? Fala.BR has the class 'linkified' which seems like a library of some sort

Answer (score 1):

There are some matches of 'col-servico' also in some comments, and comments are not tag so when you call find_all you got an error.
Here the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

[...]

for div in soup.find(class_='col-servico'):
    if isinstance(div, Tag):
        for tag in div.find_all(href=True):
            print(tag['href'])
```

Output

```
#
#
#
#
http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2011-2014/2011/lei/l12527.htm
http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2015-2018/2017/lei/l13460.htm
https://www.gov.br/pt-br/orgaos/ministerio-da-infraestrutura
```

Comment: That html I posted is inside a div with class='col-servico', thats why I use '.find'. 
 Then I use .find_all to get all links inside this div. 
I tested your code but it returns me nothing, as expected. Because there are no elements with class='col-servico' that has href.

Comment: In general, don't forget to add the error message in your question:)

Comment: at first I didn't get an error, just blank. But Now I have: NameError: name 'tag' is not defined.

I didn't find any other match for col-servico, not even in comments

Comment: yeah, I'm getting this output. It's missing the 'fala.br' link

Comment: I checked the source code and there is no such link, [no links with fala.br]. What is the full link? Are you sure that is not in some javascript function? bs4 doesn't parse js

Comment: This is the html block that contains the link: <span><a href="http://fala.BR" class="linkified" target="_blank">Fala.BR</a></span>

Comment: ... I saved the page source of your link in a file (using the browser!) and there no trace of such href="fala.BR"... that's why I cannt find it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237266/discussion-between-felipe-carminati-and-cards).